Papers related to a diophantine equations about Magic square of squares for $n=3$
The open problem of magic squares of squares explained here. Consider the following magic square of squares:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&a^2&b^2&&c^2\\\\
&d^2&e^2&&f^2\\\\
&g^2&h^2&&l^2
\end{aligned}
$$
It’s most likely that there is not any magic square of squares for $n=3$. One by some easy calculations can show that one of the requirements is:
$$
b^2+h^2=f^2+d^2=2e^2
$$
All the numbers are distinct.
Howeverthis requirement seems not possible, by some easy simulations. Of course that does not mean this equation can’t be satisfied and it just hints that is less likely to happen.  I was not able to find good related papers in recent decades addressing these equations directly. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide any useful possible related papers in the past two decades that could possibly be helpful to read regarding this equation.
Edit #1: I apologize, I did not use good parameters in software and I made a mistake. The equations have answers. Check @davidlowryduda's answer.
Edit #2: I think since we should have the following equations:
$$
c^2+g^2=a^2+l^2=b^2+h^2=f^2+d^2=2e^2
$$
Only three of these equations can be satisfied at most.

Hello! I suggest you read more about pythagorean triples and how they are related to gaussian integers and primes of the form $x^2+y^2$ / $4k+1$. That is because your requirement is equivalent to the existence of two distinct pythagorean triples with the same hypotenuse. You might also enjoy the book "Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$" by David A. Cox if you then want to broaden your study.

Thank you very much. I will definitely look into it.

Great :-) Once you have done so you will realize that (and why) you can construct arbitrarily many distinct sums of two squares that equal $e^2$ or $2e^2$.

Some recent papers on closely related problems: https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.09364,
https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.08161

Why it's important to have papers from "recent decades"? What is not "good" about older papers?

I don't think you're going to find much literature on the sub problem you identify.

However, this requirement seems not possible...

This doesn't seem impossible to me from trivial reasoning (such as congruence or local conditions). For example,
$$ 35^2 + 5^2 = 31^2 + 17^2 = 2 \cdot 25^2. $$
More generally, the solutions are closely connected to rational points on a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$. Any such rational point $(X, Y) = (a/c, b/d)$ will satisfy
$$ X^2 + Y^2 = \left( \frac{a}{c} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{b}{d} \right)^2 = 2. $$
Clearing denominators naively gives
$$ (ad)^2 + (bc)^2 = 2 (cd)^2. $$
The problem then concerns the distribution of these rational points and the behavior of the denominators. There are infinitely many of these points and they can be parameterized in the standard way (e.g. project with lines of rational slope through $(1, 1)$).

My apologies, it seems I did not tweak my software parameters well enough.

On the internet a solution is available for semi-magic (3x3) square of squares & is shown below.
\begin{bmatrix}127&46&58\\2&113&94\\74&82&97
\end{bmatrix}
Another solution is shown below:
\begin{bmatrix}1&68&44\\76&16&23\\28&41&64
\end{bmatrix}
